# How to create typescript declaration for object literal npm module export?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I need to make a `.d.ts` file for a npm module I have this npm module https://github.com/jeremyckahn/keydrown `I am writing keydrown.d.ts`

It has a weird interface:

```
import KD from 'keydrown';
  KD.run(function KDRunTick() {KD.tick();});

  //Forward
  KD.W.press(() => dispatch({ type: "@INPUT/MOVE-FORWARD/PRESS" }));
  KD.W.up(() => dispatch({ type: "@INPUT/MOVE-FORWARD/UP" }));

  //Back
  KD.S.press(() => dispatch({ type: "@INPUT/MOVE-BACK/PRESS" }));
  KD.S.up(() => dispatch({ type: "@INPUT/MOVE-BACK/UP" }));

  //Left
  KD.A.press(() => dispatch({ type: "@INPUT/MOVE-LEFT/PRESS" }));
  KD.A.up(() => dispatch({ type: "@INPUT/MOVE-LEFT/UP" }));

///etc
```

My current `.d.ts` file looks like:

```
declare module 'keydrown' {
  interface KeyObject{
    press(callback: Function): void;
    up(callback: Function): void;
  }

  export default interface KD {
    run(callback: Function): void;
    ZERO:KeyObject
    ONE:KeyObject
    TWO:KeyObject
    THREE:KeyObject
    FOUR:KeyObject
    FIVE:KeyObject
    SEVEN:KeyObject
    EIGHT:KeyObject
    NINE:KeyObject
    A:KeyObject
    B:KeyObject
    C:KeyObject
    D:KeyObject
    E:KeyObject
    F:KeyObject
    G:KeyObject
    H:KeyObject
    I:KeyObject
    J:KeyObject
    K:KeyObject
    L:KeyObject
    M:KeyObject
    N:KeyObject
    O:KeyObject
    P:KeyObject
    Q:KeyObject
    R:KeyObject
    S:KeyObject
    T:KeyObject
    U:KeyObject
    V:KeyObject
    W:KeyObject
    X:KeyObject
    Y:KeyObject
    Z:KeyObject
    ENTER:KeyObject
    SHIFT:KeyObject
    ESC:KeyObject
    SPACE:KeyObject
    LEFT:KeyObject
    UP:KeyObject
    RIGHT:KeyObject
    DOWN:KeyObject
    BACKSPACE:KeyObject
    DELETE:KeyObject
    TAB:KeyObject
    TILDE:KeyObject
    CTRL:KeyObject
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this throws an error in the implementation:
`'KD' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. [2693]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typescript module can export both values *and* types. So when you say `export default interface` you are declaring a *type* that is exported.

Instead, you want to declare that the module exports a *value*. To do that add a `const` to your module declaration and set that as the default export.

```
const defaultExport: KD
export default defaultExport

export interface KD { ... } // removed "default"
```